# Spring confluent schema deserialize example

Tags: avro, spring-cloud-stream, confluent-platform, confluent-schema-registry

Has any one used the spring-kafka 2.0.0.Release and created a consumer that uses confluent schema registry as a source for deserializing the message ?If so can you point me to an example?

The problem I'm trying to solve is i have a Debezium CDC connector on my kafka connect platform that streams events from MongoDB as they happen. I have to intercept those events transform and re-stream. To understand the event I have to deserialize the payload. I'm currently stuck at this step.

Answer (score 1):

Sastry

This issue appears to be addressed a [while back](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/commit/36c90aa8c0acf1fe29e235b1d2aac05115fc4c90#diff-48dfa1b5f0ad75003a54618ad691e978), so I would like to point out the following test-code and the specific [part in it](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/commit/36c90aa8c0acf1fe29e235b1d2aac05115fc4c90#diff-48dfa1b5f0ad75003a54618ad691e978R223) where you can configure kafka schema-registry. 
Please take a look and see if it is clear or you need more help.